# On server side in QTcpServer appears: The remote host closed the connection

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I have a QTcpServer app and QTcpClient app.
[See my screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd4e9.png)
When a client after interacting with server is disconnecting from server, on server side appears event (in client socket - in slot):

```
void CMyClient::onSocketDisplayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{
    QString sErr = m_pClientSocket->errorString();
    m_pWin->AddMessageFormClient("Was gotten some error! " + sErr);
}
```

Error message:

> The remote host closed the connection.

After that appears an event:

```
void CMyClient::onSocketDisconnected()
{
    m_pWin->AddMessageFormClient("Client is disconnected!");
    m_pWin->UpdateDisconnectUI();
}
```

**Is it proper behavior on server side to generate `onSocketDisplayError`?**

The code to disconnect on client side:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_DisconnectFromServ_clicked()
{
    m_pSocket->disconnectFromHost();
    m_pSocket->waitForDisconnected(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with the documentation of [`QAbstractSocket`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html), that is the class behind a `QTcpSocket` and thus your client and server (emphasis mine):

> **To close the socket, call `disconnectFromHost()`. `QAbstractSocket`** enters `QAbstractSocket::ClosingState`. After all pending data has been written to the socket, `QAbstractSocket` actually closes the socket, enters `QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState`, and **emits `disconnected()`**. If you want to abort a connection immediately, discarding all pending data, call `abort()` instead. **If the remote host closes the connection, `QAbstractSocket` will emit `error(QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError)`**, during which the socket state will still be `ConnectedState`, and **then the `disconnected()` signal will be emitted**.

Therefore I'd say that:

- `disconnectFromHost` is what you should use to close the client or the server
- It's the proper behavior for the server to emit an error that indicates that a remote host closed the connection